# Is it possible to compile QtXmlPatterns on embedded linux (ARM)?

Tags: xml, qt, embedded, arm

I'd like to use XML schema validation within QT, but I can't seem to get the QtXmlPatterns module to cross compile.

I've enabled both -xmlpatterns and -exceptions in my QT configure, but the compilation still fails. Specifically:

`In file included from utils/qxpathhelper_p.h:57,
                 from acceltree/qacceltree.cpp:53:
utils/qpatternistlocale_p.h:277:2: error: #error "Patternist uses exceptions and cannot be built without."`

It's acting as if exceptions are disabled, even though I have explicitly enabled them. The compiler definitely supports exceptions... is there something in QT ARM that forces them to be "off" even if I request them? Is the XML patterns module just wanky and should I avoid it? I noticed it wants member templates and other compiler features that the rest of QT kindly works without.

Comment: It looks like 'PHONON' may define 'QT_NO_EXCEPTIONS'.  Try configuring with '-no-phonon-backend -no-phonon'.